# PyCharm code color disappears when configuring python interpreter

Tags: pycharm

When I open my `py-files` before configuring `Python` interpreter in `PyCharm (v2.7.2)`, my code shows up in `color`.

Once I `configure` **Python interpreter (3.3.2)**, all the colors disappear.

When I open `Python` exercise files from the book "**Introduction to Programming using Python**" which I have downloaded, the `code/syntax` in the `exercise file` is colored. I have reinstalled several times, searched forums and not been able to work out what is happening.

Here's the link for one of the project files, idea.log and screenshots showing the problem (note "eval", "input", and "print" not highlighted:
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=53169E23AE3932A6!3922&authkey=!ANuJ5VPiOM0hKHA

Appreciate any help on this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the Python SDK that you are using. With 2.7.2 these keywords are highlighted using `Keyword` coloring, but with Python 3.x they are resolved as `Built-in name` and are highlighted as such, you can [customize it here](http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/5018/20130529164148.png).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! My files are associated correctly and "invalidate caches" didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Please share a sample project to reproduce the problem and add [idea.log](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23352446) to the archive.

Comment: OK, I'll update my question with the source code, but how do I add "idea.log" to the archive?

Comment: You can zip your project with idea.log and share it via some public service, Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: Link added to view file + idea.log

Comment: Where is idea.log? I can't reproduce the problem, code is highlighted, [see this screenshot](http://img20.imageshack.us/img20/6844/20130529150001.png). If you don't like the default scheme, change it in `Settings` | `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts`.

Comment: Sorry, the idea.log is included now. I don't understand why exercise filesturn up ok. The problem persists for my current project files and also if I create a new project with new files in that project. (I'm using the "Darcula" theme by the way.)

Comment: OK, screenshot from my file and working exercise file uploaded. Thanks.

Comment: I did an experiment: Only the keywords "eval", "input" and "print" doesn't show up in color! Please see screenshot in above link.

Comment: I think it depends on the Python SDK that you are using. With 2.7.2 these keywords are highlighted using `Keyword` coloring, but with Python 3.x they are resolved as `Built-in` name and are highlighted as such, you can customize it [here](http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/5018/20130529164148.png).

Comment: Does that explain why the same keywords in the exercise files turn up highlighted...?

Comment: It may be a different project with Python 2.7 set as the interpreter instead of 3.x.

Comment: When I add one of the exercise files to my project folder, the same three keywords loose their color. But this is strange as the book and files are based on Python 3.

Comment: So, if you use Python 3, highlighting is different, see the screenshot above for the place where you can change it.